# How to show Bengali Language in Codeblocks

Tags: c, unicode

I am facing a problem to show Bengali language output in codeblocks . I want to write Bengali language .I know it can be done with the help of unicode . The unicode of "ঈ" is 2440 . So I write the following small program .

```
       #include<stdio.h>

       int main()
       {
           int i;
           char ch = 2440;
           printf("%c",ch);
           return 0;
      }
```

But the above program does not show "ঈ" . Why ? What should I do in order to show Bengali language in codeblocks .Plz guyz help me to solve this problem .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `char`, it is stored in 1 byte, and thus can only store up-to 256 (or -127 - 128). This means that 2440 will get truncated, and that's one reason why it is not working.

Instead of `printf` and `char` you need to use functions and types from [wchar.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/), specifically [wchar_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wchar_t/) and something like [wprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wprintf/) .

```
 wprintf (L"Character: %lc %lc \n", L'ঈ', 2440);
```

p.s. I realise they are c++ based resources, but they are talking about the C library, and they should work regardless.

Comment: After adding the above line, I have no output in console . Why ?

Comment: @OcenaPothik probably because you are using an Ascii-based console .. switch to a Unicode-based console to be able to get the output correctly